# Tensorflow: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, tf-idf, autoencoder

I am trying to extract my embedded matrix and normalize it to run cosine similarity.
following this github repo:
https://github.com/s4sarath/Deep-Learning-Projects/blob/master/variational_text_inference/model_evaluation.ipynb

```py
embedding_matrix = find_norm(embedding_matrix)
```

I have a function defined for this:

```py
def find_norm(syn0):
    syn0norm = (syn0 / np.sqrt((syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]).astype(np.float32)
    #syn0norm = (syn0 / sqrt((syn0 ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]).astype(REAL)
    return syn0norm
```

But when I run it, I get the above error. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding a TensorFlow `Tensor` object to the `find_norm` function, which expects a numpy array instead.

You can either run the tensorflow graph, extract the graph, and feed it to your `find_norm` function, or you could rewrite the function to work with tensor objects (and output a tensor).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to tensorflow. Can you help me here?

Comment: you coud try using the tensorflow operation `tf.make_ndarray()` to generate a numpy array from the `embedding_matrix` Tensor object.
Try adding  `embedding_matrix = tf.make_ndarray(embedding_matrix)` after cell 7

Comment: Throws this error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'

Comment: Ah, in eager execution mode you can apparently directly call `.numpy()` to a tensor object. 

try: `embedding_matrix =  embedding_matrix.numpy()`

Comment: throws this error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: perhaps `embedding_matrix = embedding_matrix.eval()` ?

Comment: ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`...shows this. I haven't enabled the eager execution. Can the problem be because of that?

Comment: Used this                                                                                                                              
    with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ...  
    embedding_matrix = embedding_matrix.eval()                                                               and then                                                                                                                      embedding_matrix = find_norm(embedding_matrix)                                                           worked. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps we're better off trying to convert the `find_norm` function to work with tensors.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. Stuck at one more place. Should I ask here?

Comment: sure thing! What's the issue?

Comment: I am finding the similarity of my passed documents referring to this github repo:https://github.com/s4sarath/Deep-Learning-Projects/blob/master/variational_text_inference/model_evaluation.ipynb. After I normalize the embedded matrix.

Comment: I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406994/how-to-handle-errors-in-arrays-and-sequence